# TypeScript doesn't infer the type of passed generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define flexible types for my api responses, but can't figure out how to approach type conversion using TypeScript 4.5.4.
I'd like to parse the response and get the type that I'll be using later in the code, the response type is just for proper typing before parse.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQIYDsAmoBKBTAbtTB3LWABwHslZNEAnKkzAY2gDNoGJTRbcDYAoTAA8y1cBACexKlh75QAXlABvPqFDQUALlBIArgFsARpmoBuVToT7M22OGrQkAc3NrqCcI6fa9Rk664cPHxbey9zAF9zAWFSUQkpDCCCIjIKKkVU8koAFUlMAB4ZYIA%20aJAIGHg4RFAnTCQTBAAbBKpiZoQGTDRMZsp8SBNMGJExcHykkmzMPKkCgElwTH0ShWULDR8DYzMLDzDDXWXYbRU1NQBtAGtMcVCHZwBdbSWViwi%20T74K4gRqSjUUDMXRIBiecgcLigxDMZZA5iYcAMGDOSpUFAeBB8EFgiFIUB-AGYLLpAAUmPACG0xRSmGm6UuTwAlDTkvgmRs3EjdNQCZSEAA6fQIYhksnQZb6ZkKNbnC60cC8gnyi7qLTqKWCjQAGgsasFhslK0FBwcRxOerVUQ%20zMiQA) (EDIT: fixed id)

```
// this and ReviewResponse are specific to reviews
export type Review = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  rating: number;
  review: string;
};

export type ReviewResponse = ResponseType<Review>;

// this is a general type placed elsewhere
export type ResponseType<Item> = {
  id: number;
  attributes: {
    [key: string]: Item
  }
}

// parser function to run after fetching the data
function parseResponse(data: ReviewResponse[]): Review[] {
  return data.map((item) => {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      ...item.attributes,
    };
  });
}
```

Function `parseResponse` has an error visible below.
Why TS doesn't understand that Item is of type Review, what am I missing?:

```
Type '{ id: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Review[]'.
  Type '{ id: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Review': name, rating, review (2322)
```

Comment: Your Review id is string, but your response's id is integer. Maybe this is causing the problem?

Comment: @YSFKBDY right, I changed it but it doesn't change the situation with missing `name, rating, review`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `attributes` contains an object with the other attributes of the object it's type should be `Item`, or more specifically `Omit<Item, 'id'>`.

```
export type ResponseType<Item> = {
  id: string;
  attributes: Omit<Item, 'id'>
}

// parser function to run after fetching the data
function parseResponse(data: ReviewResponse[]): Review[] {
  return data.map((item) => {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      ...item.attributes,
    };
  });
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQIYDsAmoBKBTAbtTB3LWABwHslZNEAnKkzAY2gDNoGJTRbcDYAoTAA8y1cBACexKlh75QAXlABvPqFDQUALlCxw1aEgDmAblWgkCALaZtu-UdNrqCcAcPakAV0sAjTNUcuHDx8Wz03UwBfUwFhUlEJKQxggiIyCipFNPJKABVJTAAeGRCAPhiQCBh4OERQQ0wkfwQAG0SqYhaEBkw0TBbKfEh-TFiRMXAC5JIczHypQoBJcExLUoVlMw0w+xMzF3CfTxXYbQB5S2hwJZXLABpQAHINR9K+SL4+SuIEakpqUDMTxIBiucgcLjAxDMFYA5iYcAMGBGKpUFAuBB8IEgsFIUA-P6YbIZAAU6PACG0JVSmBmGQA2gBdACUVJS+CZmycCM81Dx5IQADpLAhiCSSVdVsyFOsVGpueBeXi5fK1Nt1LdBRo7mZVYL9ZLLIKDvojicdaromZIsyokA)

`[key: string]: Item` means that attributes could have multiple `Item` properties under different keys. So it could be something like `{ "A": { /*attributes of Review*/ }, "B": { /*attributes of Review*/ } }`

Comment: ```
Type '{ name: string; rating: number; review: string; id: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Review[]'.
  Type '{ name: string; rating: number; review: string; id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Review'.
    Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.```

Comment: @TaghiKhavari There is no error in my playground link. The issue with the differing ids was discussed in comments. Those should be in agreement

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thank you, that works, I knew I missed some simple rule